# Background Sections Flashing on Mobile Devices

Tags: responsive

i have this code on my clients wordpress site and is working on desktop but not on mobile. it is literally flashing these codes only. this question is related to website: bntiarms.com

[fullwidth background_color="#959698" background_image="" background_parallax="none" enable_mobile="yes" parallax_speed=0.3 background_repeat="no-repeat" background_position="left top" video_url="" video_aspect_ratio="16:9" video_webm="" video_mp4="" video_ogv="" video_preview_image="" overlay_color="" overlay_opacity="0.5" video_mute="yes" video_loop="yes" fade="no" border_size="0px" border_color="" border_style="solid" padding_top="0" padding_bottom="0" padding_left="" padding_right="" hundred_percent="no" equal_height_columns="no" hide_on_mobile="no" menu_anchor="" class="" id=""][separator style_type="none" top_margin="5px" bottom_margin="" sep_color="" border_size="" icon="" icon_circle="" icon_circle_color="" width="" alignment="center" class="" id=""][/fullwidth][fullwidth background_color="" background_image="" background_parallax="none" enable_mobile="yes" parallax_speed=0.3 background_repeat="no-repeat" background_position="left top" video_url="" video_aspect_ratio="16:9" video_webm="" video_mp4="" video_ogv="" video_preview_image="" overlay_color="" overlay_opacity="0.5" video_mute="yes" video_loop="yes" fade="no" border_size="0px" border_color="" border_style="solid" padding_top="" padding_bottom="" padding_left="" padding_right="" hundred_percent="no" equal_height_columns="no" hide_on_mobile="no" menu_anchor="" class="" id=""][fusion_text]

Equipment you can rely on when the mission is critical

[/fusion_text][/fullwidth][fullwidth background_color="" background_image="" background_parallax="none" enable_mobile="yes" parallax_speed=0.3 background_repeat="no-repeat" background_position="left top" video_url="" video_aspect_ratio="16:9" video_webm="" video_mp4="" video_ogv="" video_preview_image="" overlay_color="" overlay_opacity="0.5" video_mute="yes" video_loop="yes" fade="no" border_size="0px" border_color="" border_style="solid" padding_top="" padding_bottom="0px" padding_left="" padding_right="" hundred_percent="no" equal_height_columns="no" hide_on_mobile="no" menu_anchor="" class="" id="topdiv"][fusion_text]

i tried changing the "no" to "yes" in enable_mobile="yes" but in mobile it still displays enable_mobile="no"